# Ionic 2 accessing JSON elements

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

I have this function

```
downlaod(){
        console.log('ab')
        this.JobsServiceProvider.getResume().then(result=>{ 

        })
    }
```

that returns this json

> {"resume":{"owner_id":131461,"filename":"cvabdulmuizzabdulhalimislamicstudies.doc","location":"asset.jobstore.com/uploads/document/131461","status":1,"owner_type":"jobseeker","id":2330482,"createdAt":"2017-06-22T08:11:56.000Z","updatedAt":"2017-06-22T08:11:56.000Z"}}

how can i access it,I tried result.resume, result.owner_id. It doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your service should return response  in json format.

```
this.http.get(url)
               .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json())
           .catch(this.handleError);
```

In your component you need access json

```
downlaod(){
        console.log('ab')
        this.JobsServiceProvider.getResume().then(result=>{
         console.log(result);
// access result 
          result.owner_id
        })
    }
```

you can  do console.log(result)to check whether your are receiving json